# How to find the installed pandas version

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble with some of pandas functionalities. How do I check what is my installation version?

Answer (score 469, accepted):

Check `pandas.__version__`:

```
In [76]: import pandas as pd

In [77]: pd.__version__
Out[77]: '0.12.0-933-g281dc4e'
```

Pandas also provides a utility function, `pd.show_versions()`, which reports the version of its dependencies as well:

```
In [53]: pd.show_versions(as_json=False)

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.6.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.13.0-45-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.15.2-113-g5531341
nose: 1.3.1
Cython: 0.21.1
numpy: 1.8.2
scipy: 0.14.0.dev-371b4ff
statsmodels: 0.6.0.dev-a738b4f
IPython: 2.0.0-dev
sphinx: 1.2.2
patsy: 0.3.0
dateutil: 1.5
pytz: 2012c
bottleneck: None
tables: 3.1.1
numexpr: 2.2.2
matplotlib: 1.4.2
openpyxl: None
xlrd: 0.9.3
xlwt: 0.7.5
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: 3.3.3
bs4: 4.3.2
html5lib: 0.999
httplib2: 0.8
apiclient: None
rpy2: 2.5.5
sqlalchemy: 0.9.8
pymysql: None
psycopg2: 2.4.5 (dt dec mx pq3 ext)
```

Comment: this seems to be outdated `>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '__version__'
`

Comment: @jangorecki: `pd.__version__` is [defined here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/__init__.py#L85). If you are getting an `AttributeError`, it seems more likely that `import pandas as pd` is either importing the wrong module (as could happen if you created a file called pandas.py) or there is some other problem with your installation.

Comment: yes problem was that pandas was installed with sudo while python started without sudo.

Answer (score 63):

Run:

```
pip list
```

You should get a list of packages (including pandas) and their versions, e.g.:

```
beautifulsoup4 (4.5.1)
cycler (0.10.0)
jdcal (1.3)
matplotlib (1.5.3)
numpy (1.11.1)
openpyxl (2.2.0b1)
pandas (0.18.1)
pip (8.1.2)
pyparsing (2.1.9)
python-dateutil (2.2)
python-nmap (0.6.1)
pytz (2016.6.1)
requests (2.11.1)
setuptools (20.10.1)
six (1.10.0)
SQLAlchemy (1.0.15)
xlrd (1.0.0)
```

Comment: pip  list | grep pandas

Comment: `pip list | findstr pandas` - for Windows

Answer (score 24):

**Simplest Solution**

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

> **Its double underscore before and after the word "version".

**Output:**

```
'0.14.1'
```

Answer (score 11):

Run

```
pip freeze
```

It works the same as above.

```
pip show pandas
```

Displays information about a specific package.
For more information, check out `pip help`

Answer (score 11):

**Windows**

```
python -c "import pandas as pd; print(pd.__version__)"
conda list | findstr pandas  # Anaconda / Conda
pip freeze | findstr pandas
pip show pandas | findstr Version
```

**Linux**

```
python -c "import pandas as pd; print(pd.__version__)"
conda list | grep pandas  # Anaconda / Conda
pip freeze | grep pandas  # pip
```

Answer (score 5):

In a jupyter notebook cell: `pip freeze | grep pandas`

```
pip freeze | grep pandas

pandas==0.25.3
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages
```

Comment: In my Jupyter notebook, `pandas.__version__` and `!pip freeze | grep pandas` show two different versions. Which version is being used in the notebook?

Comment: Disregard. Had to restart kernel. Now both match.

Comment: To filter out packages that include the same name: pip freeze | grep ^pandas==