# Pandas - looping through columns of a dataframe and join this column with other dataframe

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a DataFrame (df1)

```
index abc bcd def 
20150101 0.5 0.3 0.2
20150102 0.7 0.9 1.6
20150103 1.7 2.9 4.6
.................
```

second dataframe (df2)

```
index a b c ...(about 100 columns)
0 0 1 8 ...
1 9 5 3 ...
2 2 3 7 ..
```

I would like to loop through each column in 2nd dataframe and need to form a dataframe in every loop like

```
 index abc bcd def col
 20150101 0.5 0.3 0.2 0
 20150102 0.7 0.9 1.6 9
 20150103 1.7 2.9 4.6 2
```

and need to work on this new dataframe for other calculations

I am running this,

```
    for col in df2.iteritems():
        df1['new_col'] = col
```

with error: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

If I form a series from col as in

```
    for col in df2.iteritems():
        c = col[1].astype(float)
        s = pd.Series(c)
         dfb['col'] = s
```

gives

```
index abc bcd def col
20150101 0.5 0.3 0.2 NaN
20150102 0.7 0.9 1.6 NaN
20150103 1.7 2.9 4.6 NaN
```

please suggest a solution. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
for col in df2.columns:
    print pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),df2[col]], axis=1)

      index  abc  bcd  def  a
0  20150101  0.5  0.3  0.2  0
1  20150102  0.7  0.9  1.6  9
2  20150103  1.7  2.9  4.6  2
      index  abc  bcd  def  b
0  20150101  0.5  0.3  0.2  1
1  20150102  0.7  0.9  1.6  5
2  20150103  1.7  2.9  4.6  3
      index  abc  bcd  def  c
0  20150101  0.5  0.3  0.2  8
1  20150102  0.7  0.9  1.6  3
2  20150103  1.7  2.9  4.6  7
```

EDIT:

IIUC you need select only `DataFrames`, where in last column is at least one value `1`, use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
dfs = {}

for col in df2.columns:
    df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),df2[col]], axis=1)
    #print df
    if (df2[col] == 1).any():
        print df
        #storing in dictionary of dataframes  
        dfs[col] = df
      index  abc  bcd  def  b
0  20150101  0.5  0.3  0.2  1
1  20150102  0.7  0.9  1.6  5
2  20150103  1.7  2.9  4.6  3       

print dfs['b']        
      index  abc  bcd  def  b
0  20150101  0.5  0.3  0.2  1
1  20150102  0.7  0.9  1.6  5
2  20150103  1.7  2.9  4.6  3
```

Comment: I would like to access only one column from the df2 in each loop and join that with the df1

Comment: So what is result?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot concatenate list of ['DataFrame', 'Series']

Comment: What is your version of `pandas`? `print pd.show_versions()`

Comment: And version of pandas?

Comment: Maybe help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612645/how-to-find-the-installed-pandas-version)

Comment: Hmmm, there is problem. The last vesrion is `0.18.0`. I think you can update your `pandas`.

Comment: It seems, I don't have permission to upgrade (or throws error: permission denied: 'tzinfo.py')

Comment: I tested in a virtual environment with pandas 0.18.0. It still gives the table with the last column which is from df2 as NaN.   UPDATE: All my data in df2 is binary. It will be okay to select the final table as last column from df2, where col==1 in each loop

Comment: well the first solution worked with little modification                      instead of              pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),df2[col]], axis=1)      I used   pd.concat([df1,df2[col]], axis=1).reset_index()