# Concatenate several columns across more than one row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I  have a pandas dataframe. I would like to concatenate several columns based on one column with an identifier. There may be more than one row of columns that need to be concatenated. I am working with strings only.

So for instance, I  have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 Identifier     Op1 Op2 Op3
 A     str_1    str_2   str_3
 B     str_4    str_5   str_6
 B     str_7    str_8   str_9
 B     str_10   str_11  str_12
 C     str_13   str_14  str_15 
 C     str_16   str_17  str_18
```

I need everyone in Op1, Op2, and Op3 concatenated. If the same "identifier" is on more than one row, I need Op1, Op2, and Op3 columns concatenated and then concatenated with the first column.

So my end result should look like this:

```
 Identifier Ops
 A  str_1 str_2 str_3
 B  str_4 str_5 str_6 str_7 str_8 str_9 str_10 str_11 str_12
 C  str_13 str_14 str_15 str_16 str_17 str_18
```

There should be a space in between each "thing" as well. So like 'str_8 str_9' instead of 'str_8str_9'

I also have this table in sqlite3 if that is easier to work with than pandas.

How do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning your input data into a csv file, I did the following, and it works well.

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.read_csv("CombinerData.csv")

print DF
print 

def combine_Columns_Into_New_Column(DF, columns_To_Combine, new_Column_Name):
    DF[new_Column_Name] = ''
    for Col in columns_To_Combine:
        DF[new_Column_Name] += DF[Col].map(str) + ' '
    DF = DF.drop(columns_To_Combine, axis=1)
    DF = DF.groupby(by=['Identifier']).sum()

    return DF

DF = combine_Columns_Into_New_Column(DF, ['Op1','Op2','Op3'],'Ops')

print DF
```

OUTPUT:

```
                                                          Ops
Identifier                                                   
A                                          str_1 str_2 str_3 
B           str_4 str_5 str_6 str_7 str_8 str_9 str_10 str...
C                 str_13 str_14 str_15  str_16 str_17 str_18
```

INPUT FILE:

```
Identifier,Op1,Op2,Op3
A,str_1,str_2,str_3
B,str_4,str_5,str_6
B,str_7,str_8,str_9
B,str_10,str_11,str_12
C,str_13,str_14,str_15 
C,str_16,str_17,str_18
```

Comment: This almost works for me. The new DF doesn't have the new column appended though? How do I fix that?

Comment: @ifthenifthen, I ran it again just like I posted it, and it is working just as I reported it. I am using python 2.7. Double check your code and input file. If you put your code and input in some remote git repo, I can help you troubleshoot. I've also added the input file structure in an edit above.

Comment: Would it matter if there are other columns in my actual input file?

Comment: If I run it exactly as you have written above, but with the following change: "
DF2 = combine_Columns_Into_New_Column(DF, ['Op1','Op2','Op3'],'Ops')" then DF2 shows my input file with the columns to be combined missing, and no extra column. But DF shows an extra column without the columns dropped, however multiple rows are not aggregated. So it works like "Identifier A" but not "Identifier B". If I set it equal to DF to begin with, then the columns are simply dropped and there is no extra column.

Comment: Would you please follow instructions of first answer to this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612645/how-to-find-the-installed-pandas-version and report your pandas version?

Comment: My pandas version is 0.19.2

Comment: This is very strange. I noticed that you are having issues with other method answers too. I have tested this on Linux (Ubuntu based) and Windows 7 Pro. My best guess is that there is something not quite right with your pandas install.

Comment: Using your repo examples, I've reproduced your issue even when using converting your input to csv format. Working to understand the issues.

Comment: I can't tell you how grateful I am for your continued attention to this

Comment: I deleted the comment with my github link now that you have it.

Comment: OK and no worries. Happy to help. See issue on GitHub now.

Answer (score 2):

With your input DataFrame called `df`, try the following:

```
from itertools import chain
df.groupby('Identifier')['Op1', 'Op2', 'Op3']\
  .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(list(chain(*x.values.tolist()))))\
  .reset_index()\
  .rename(columns={0:'Ops'})
```

Comment: I got as far as reset_index().  Then I got the following error:
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: I manage to replicate that error by running the groupby twice i.e. something like `df.groupby(...)[...].groupby(...)`, so maybe doublecheck you aren't doing that. Otherwise the code seems to work for me.

Comment: I tried again, and confirmed I was not doing the error you described. So far the only changes I have made is to set the groupby equal to df2. If it matters, there are more columns in my actual dataset than I described in the example above. I cannot do either of your last two steps - I get the same error for both.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [168]: (df.set_index('Identifier')
     ...:    .T
     ...:    .agg(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=' '))
     ...:    .groupby(level=0)
     ...:    .agg(' '.join)
     ...:    .reset_index(name='Ops'))
     ...:
Out[168]:
  Identifier                                                Ops
0          A                                  str_1 str_2 str_3
1          B  str_4 str_5 str_6 str_7 str_8 str_9 str_10 str...
2          C          str_13 str_14 str_15 str_16 str_17 str_18
```

Comment: I am attempting this solution - I got the error that 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'. I am using python 2.7.

Comment: @ifthenifthen, it won't work if your Pandas version < 0.20.0. Try to upgrade Pandas or use @ ags29's solution