# How to concatenate values of the same column based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a table which looks like this -

```
date        name        values      items
01-03-2019  xyz         900         NaN
NaN         NaN         900         brush
02-03-2019  abc        1200         NaN
NaN         NaN         900         paste
NaN         NaN         300         floss
```

and desired output is -

```
date            name       values        items
01-03-2019      xyz        900           brush
02-03-2019      abc        1200          paste, floss
```

I know I can use np.where() to make the values of each item NaN, but I don't know how I should go about the concatenation and then move the result up alongside the name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas: Groupby Sum AND Concatenate Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600818/python-pandas-groupby-sum-and-concatenate-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with first column and `ffill` for forward filling missing values and dictionary, which is created dynamic - for each column without `date` and `items` is applied aggregate function [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and for last column `items` is used `join` with removed missing values:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['date','items']), 'first')
d['items'] = lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna())
df = df.groupby(df['date'].ffill()).agg(d).reset_index()
print (df)
         date name  values         items
0  01-03-2019  xyz     900         brush
1  02-03-2019  abc    1200  paste, floss
```

If only few columns is possible pass 2 columns to `groupby` with `ffill` and create dictionary passed to `agg`:

```
df = (df.groupby([df['date'].ffill(), df['name'].ffill()])
       .agg({'values':'first', 'items':lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna())})
       .reset_index())
print (df)
         date name  values         items
0  01-03-2019  xyz     900         brush
1  02-03-2019  abc    1200  paste, floss
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Could you please explain the first line? What exactly is it doing?

Comment: @rik_maz - Added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fillna` with `forwardfill (ffill)`. Then `dropna` and at the same time `groupby` with `agg` to get the `sum` of value and concat the strings in items:

```
df[['date', 'name']] = df[['date', 'name']].fillna(method='ffill')

df = df.dropna().groupby('date').agg({'name':'first',
                                      'values':'sum',
                                      'items':', '.join}).reset_index()

print(df)
         date name  values         items
0  01-03-2019  xyz     900         brush
1  02-03-2019  abc    1200  paste, floss
```