# pandas method ' rolling_mean ' can not use

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
           'b':[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
                          })

pd.rolling_mean(df,window = 2)
```

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'

pandas document http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html

I do know why i get this error, pandas docement show this information.
And I can not use it ? 
Indeed,all the method like this happened same problem
eg:(pandas.rolling_median) 
   (pandas.rolling_var)

By the way, argument ''window'' , how to use it?

Comment: In current versions [it is now](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) `rolling(window=2).mean()`.

Comment: which pandas version are you using?

Comment: how can i search the pandas document that i need

Comment: import pandas as pd
print pd.__version__

Comment: Pandas also provides a utility function, pd.show_versions(), which reports the version of its dependencies as well, reference:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612645/how-to-find-the-installed-pandas-version