# Fixing library import for python

Tags: python, pandas

I have trouble running this simple code chunk

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pandas import read_csv


url = "/Users/maya/Documents/UPEM/Cours/M2/Big Data/ML_Test/base_earthquake.csv"
quakes = pd.read_csv(url)


print(quakes.columns)
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ml_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I tried this command

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

but it does not seem to work

Comment: Do you have multiple version of Python installed?

Comment: Please list what operating system, os version, and version of python you are using

Comment: Please can you let us know what version of pandas you are using too?  There is a comprehensive answer here on how to check pandas version, plus its dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612645/how-to-find-the-installed-pandas-version

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
from pandas import read_csv
```

then you should call it like:

```
quakes = read_csv(url)
```

otherwise do

```
import pandas as pd
```

and it should work